# Derivative and inverse

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, derivatives, inverse-function

Is there a function whos derivative of its inverse equals the inverse of its derivative? This may also hold on a specific interval only.
$$\frac{d}{dx}f^{\langle-1\rangle}(x)=\left(\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)^{\langle-1\rangle}$$
Considering that $f(x)=x$ is its own inverse and $e^x$ is its own derivative, neither of them satisfies the equation, but both are the only functions with the respective properties (over the reels). Is this already a proof that there is no solution to the above equation?

Also, I dont know much about complex analysis but if a complex-valued function meets the criteria I'd be happy to know too :)

Comment: A little bit of progress, plugging in $f'(x)$ on both sides gives the equation $$\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(f'(x)))} = x$$

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2117928

Comment: See as well https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2617954

Comment: There's something weird going on. The above statement implies there exists a function $g$ such that $$\frac{1}{g(0)} = 0$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi how did you get there?

Comment: Plug the  Ansatz $f(x):=a x^\beta$ into your identity, and you will obtain equations for (complex) $\beta$ and $a$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I got $\frac{d}{dx}f^{\langle -1 \rangle}(x)=\frac{\sqrt[b]{x/a}}{bx}$ and $\left(\frac{d}{dx}f(x) \right)^{\langle -1 \rangle}=\sqrt[b-1]{\frac{x}{ab}}$, is this correct?

Comment: @NinadMunshi. Would you please explain a bit how exactly you derived that?

Comment: As far as I can see, Christian Blatter's Ansatz doesn'tlead to a solution.

Comment: @HandeBruijn do you have a better idea?

Comment: Unfortunately NO, so far. It's on my wish list, though :-)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have a very nice solution. In order to have the inverse of both the function and the derivative of the function exist, it must be true that both $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ don't change sign (and aren't $0$ for any interval). Then I think it's impossible for the sign of the first derivative of the LHS and the RHS to be equal to each other given the prior restrictions.

Comment: I had to mention this à-propos [Youtube suggestion]( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNUfiQgj6ZI) whose solution is of the form suggested by Chritian Blatter!! Unfortunately there is no video about our problem...\\ By the way, one could also write the equation with both $\langle -1 \rangle$ on the l.h.s., it looks better...

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer.** In view of comments issued, and by growing insight, this answer must be considered as a partial one.

The easiest way is to start with considering the derivatives. Let $g(x)=f'(x)$.
Then $g(x)$ must have an inverse $g^{-1}(x)$. This means that $y=g(x)$ is monotonically increasing or decreasing.
$$
\mbox{Increasing:} \quad \begin{cases}
x_1 \lt x_2 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad y_1 \lt y_2 \\
x_1 \gt x_2 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad y_1 \gt y_2
\end{cases} \\
\mbox{Decreasing:} \quad \begin{cases}
x_1 \lt x_2 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad y_1 \gt y_2 \\
x_1 \gt x_2 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad y_1 \lt y_2
\end{cases}
$$
The inverse $g^{-1}(x)$ is obtained (graphically) by mirroring $g(x)$ in the line $y=x$, thus by exchanging $x$ and $y$.
From this it clear that $g(x)$ and $g^{-1}(x)$ must be both monotonically increasing or both be monotonically decreasing.

The same considerations are valid for $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ as well, because these two are each others inverse too.

But $g(x)$ is also a derivative. If this derivative would become zero somewhere, then $f(x)$ would no longer be monotonic at that place.
So $g(x)$ must be nonzero everywhere in its domain.
For the inverse $g^{-1}(x)$ this means that there cannot be an intersection with the $y$-axis.
Without loss of generality, we may assume that both $g(x)$ and $g^{-1}(x)$ are defined in the first quadrant, for $x \gt 0$ and $y \gt 0$.
Other cases are covered by re-defining $g$ using symmetry: $g(x) := g(-x)$ , $g(x) := -g(x)$ , $g(x) := -g(-x)$.

Before proceeding, a few examples will be presented. First example:
$$
f'(x) = g(x) = 1/x \quad ; \quad [f'(x)]^{-1} = g^{-1}(x) = 1/x \\ 
f(x) = \int_1^x\frac{dt}{t} = \ln(x) = y \quad ; \quad x = \ln(y) \; \Rightarrow \; f^{-1}(x) = e^x \quad ; \quad [f^{-1}]'(x) = e^x
$$
It is noticed that $[f'(x)]^{-1}$ is monotonically *decreasing* while $[f^{-1}]'(x)$ is monotonically *increasing*.
Second example:
$$
f'(x) = g(x) = \sqrt{x} \quad ; \quad [f'(x)]^{-1} = x^2 \\
f(x) = \int_0^x\sqrt{t}\,dt = \frac{2}{3}x^{3/2} \quad ; \quad x = \frac{2}{3}y^{3/2}
\; \Rightarrow \; f^{-1}(x) = \left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)^{2/3} \quad ; \quad [f^{-1}]'(x) = \left(\frac{3x}{2}\right)^{-1/3}
$$
It is noticed that $[f'(x)]^{-1}$ is monotonically *increasing* while $[f^{-1}]'(x)$ is monotonically *decreasing*.

A pattern is emerging. Let's consider now the general case for $g(x)=f'(x)$ monotonically decreasing. It will be assumed
that the reader is able to construct the analogue for monotonically increasing $g(x)$.
Then $[f'(x)]^{-1}$ is monotonically decreasing as well. Define the function $f(x)$ as a **definite integral**
[*in statu nascendi*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_statu_nascendi) (a Riemann sum). For example as:
$$
\sum_i g\left(x_i\right)\left(x_{i+1}-x_i\right) \approx \int_a^x g(t)\,dt = f(x)
$$
And select the subdivisions in such a way that
$$
g\left(x_i\right)\left(x_{i+1}-x_i\right) = \mbox{constant} = dA
$$
Then we can construct the inverse function $f(x)$ by numerical approximation.
It is clear thar if $g(x_i)$ is decreasing, then the area $dA$ can only kept constant by increasing the intervals $\left(x_{i+1}-x_i\right)$.
This means that the intervals of $f^{-1}(x_i)$ must be *increasing*, because of $\left(x_{i+1}-x_i\right)\to\left(y_{i+1}-y_i\right)$.
But then the derivative of $f^{-1}(x_i)$ is equal to $\left(y_{i+1}-y_i\right)/dA$, which means that $[f^{-1}]'(x)$ is increasing numerically,
therefore analytically when taking limits. So here comes our end-result,
apart from technicalities to filled in by the questioner eventually.

**Theorem.**
$[f'(x)]^{-1}$ is monotonically *decreasing* if and only if $[f^{-1}]'(x)$ is monotonically *increasing*.
$[f'(x)]^{-1}$ is monotonically *increasing* if and only if $[f^{-1}]'(x)$ is monotonically *decreasing*.
Therefore **it is impossible** to find (real valued) functions $f$ with $[f'(x)]^{-1}=[f^{-1}]'(x)$.

EDIT.

Below is a visualization of the technique employed, for the special example
$f'(x)=[f'(x)]^{-1}=1/x$ , $\color{red}{f(x)=\ln(x)}$ , $\color{green}{f^{-1}(x)=[f^{-1}]'(x)=e^x}$ .
Further specifications: $-0.1 \le x \le 9$ ; $-0.1 \le y \le 9$ ; $dA = 1/10$ ;

thick colored lines numerically, thin colored lines analytically.

[image]

BUG FIX.

The domains of interest are much trickier than I thought.

Counter example. Consider $f(x)=1/x$, defined for $x\gt 0,y\gt 0$. Then $f'(x)=-1/x^2$ is defined for $x\gt 0,y\lt 0$;
$[f'(x)]^{-1}=\sqrt{-1/x}$ is defined for $x\lt 0,y\gt 0$ and *increasing*; $f^{-1}(x)=1/x$ is defined for $x\gt 0,y\gt 0$;
$[f^{-1}]'(x)=-1/x^2$ is defined for $x\gt 0,y\lt 0$ and *increasing*.
So we have a problem with the first two statements of our Theorem.

**In general.** Consider $f(x)$, defined for $x\gt 0,y\gt 0$ and monotonically decreasing.
Then $f'(x)$ is defined for $x\gt 0,y\lt 0$ (i.e. negative) and monotonically increasing.
$[f'(x)]^{-1}$, because of the mirroring in $y=x$, is defined for $x\lt 0,y\gt 0$ and monotonically increasing as well.
$f^{-1}(x)$, because of the mirroring in $y=x$, is defined for $x\gt 0,y\gt 0$ and monotonically decreasing.
So $[f^{-1}]'(x)$ is defined for $x\gt 0,y\lt 0$ and monotonically increasing.
However, because of the two different domains $[f^{-1}]'(x)$ cannot be identical to $[f'(x)]^{-1}$.
Conclusion: the last statement of our Theorem remains valid, but the first two statements, in general, are wrong.

**Note.** A better numerical approximation of the integral sometimes can be obtained with the [trapezium rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule):
$$
\frac{g\left(x_i\right)+g\left(x_{i+1}\right)}{2}\left(x_{i+1}-x_i\right) = \mbox{constant} = dA = \frac{1}{n}
$$
But it does work only if $g\left(x_{i+1}\right)$ can be predicted, given the value of $dA$. In case $g(x)$ is an orthogonal hyperbola, prediction is successful:
$$
x_{i+1}-x_i=\frac{1}{n}\frac{2}{1/x_{i+1}+1/x_i}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{2x_{i+1}x_i}{x_{i+1}+x_i} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \\
n\left(x_{i+1}-x_i\right)\left(x_{i+1}+x_i\right)-2x_{i+1}x_i=nx_{i+1}^2-2x_ix_{i+1}-nx_i^2=0 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \\
x_{i+1} = \frac{x_i}{n}\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{x_i}{n}\right)^2+x_i^2}\quad \Longrightarrow\quad
x_{i+1}=x_i\left(\frac{1}{n}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}\right)
$$

Comment: How can we extend this train of thought to complex-valued functions?

Comment: @Christian: Interesting, but I'm affraid that is beyond my competence.

Comment: I didn't read through but $x\mapsto x^3$ has a vanishing derivative at $0$ but is increasing. This function really is invertible on the whole $\mathbb{R}$ although not it's derivative.\\ If a differentiable function is complex valued and invertible, then it's variable should also be 2 $\mathbb{R}$-dimensional. Restricting both the domain and the target to a 1 dimensional subspace should give a solution to the initial problem. If one requires  the function to be $\mathbb{C}$ differentiable then it is analytic, so we should have found a solution that expends as a series.

Comment: @Noix07: $f'(x)=x^3$ has an inverse $[f'(x)]^{-1}=x^{1/3}$. Both are monotonically increasing for $x\ge 0$.
$f(x)=\int_0^x t^3\,dt = x^4/4 \; \Rightarrow \; f^{-1}(x)=(4x)^{1/4} \; \Rightarrow \; [f^{-1}]'(x)=1/(4x)^{3/4}$.
The latter function is monotonically decreasing, as it should.

Comment: @HandeBruijn  I have not yet read most of the answer but it is the assertion that monotonic implies derivative non zero that is wrong.It is true that the derivative will not vanish on an interval but the example shows that $x^3$ is increasing in $\mathbb{R}$ although its derivative vanishes at 0

Comment: @HandeBruijn after reading, I think that the idea (actually from Varun Vejalla) is correct but can be directly (and rigorously) proved from the formula for $\big(f^{\langle-1\rangle}\big)'(y) = \frac{1}{f'\circ f^{-1}(y)}$ plus the fact indeed that an invertible continuous function on an interval (connected subset) is monotonic and that it is monotonic in the same "direction" as its inverse. The formula then shows that $(f^{-1})'$ and $f'$ are monotonic but in opposite direction. Nevertheless, there is a more abstract reason, cf. edit of my answer...

Comment: @Noix07: I have given you some implicit credit, with a Disclaimer augmented as the first sentence in my answer. But I cannot discover anything comprehensible in your "more abstract reason".

Comment: @HandeBruijn I first thought that the set of solutions (if not empty) was a group from which I would deduce a contradiction. Finally it turns out that it is not a group so by default I just gave an idea how to generalize the monotonicity argument with group actions. Nevertheless in any case, the idea is to show that the two sides behave differently.\\ Actually, the disclaimer is no need, my "answer" is really exploration oriented. What you could do is to write a rigorous proof of your "theorem", not with integration but with the fomula of derivation, as I mentionned in the previous comment

Answer (score 3):

**Edits:** I leave here the preliminary lines of thoughts/failed attempts. The answer based on monotonicity of the functions is probably correct and one may try to give a more abstract justification, cf. part 2.

- To begin with it is clear that the OP denotes $f^{\langle-1\rangle}$ the "reciprocal" function and not the inverse as in $\frac{1}{f}$. Hence if ever one wants to formulate the problem in algebraic terms, we need to introduce an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of functions with two products: $\times$ the pointwise product and $\circ$ the composition. The notion of derivation is readily generalized as a linear map $D:\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A}$ which satisfies the Leibniz rule w.r.t. $\times$. One can define the group $G$ of $\circ$-invertible elements and study already its image by $D$, or stable subsets etc...
- The immediate relation we get for $\mathcal{A}:=
     \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ are (to avoid confusion $g$ is the
  inverse of $f$ for $\circ$, while $h$ is the inverse of $f'$ for that
  same law, Id unit for $\circ$ while the constant $1$ function is the
  unit fo $\times$)
  $$ f\circ g=\mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb{R}}\quad \Longrightarrow\quad g' \times f'\circ g = 1\quad \label{1}\tag{1}$$
  $$ f'\circ h=\mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb{R}}="x"\quad \Longrightarrow\quad \frac{1}{x} \times f'\circ h = 1 \quad \label{2}\tag{2}$$
  with these notations, OP's equation reads $g'\overset{!}{=} h$ and by (\ref{1}): $\quad g' = \frac{1}{f'\circ g}=h$. (I assume the $\circ$-inverse are left and right inverse, as in the usual definition). What Ninad Munshi wrote on his first comment is the composition on the right of this equality with $f'$: $\quad \frac{1}{f'\circ g \circ f} = h\circ f =\mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb{R}}$. I did play with similar equalities but to no avail unfortunately... (@Christian by the way your "Feb 18" comment is correct, but for clarity you should for example use the variable $x$ for the domain and $y$ for the target space...)
- Let us examine more abstractly the behavior of $\circ$ and of $f\mapsto f^{\langle -1\rangle}$ w.r.t. $+$ and $\times$. For the derivation of a composition there is that [Faà di Bruno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) formula for derivation of composition but I was thinking more about a characterize the set $\mathcal{S}$ of solutions of the equation: does it define a subgroup/subvector space/ideal of $\mathcal{A}$. Unfortunately no, although (if not empty) $\mathcal{S}$ is stable under taking the inverse which we may denote $\mathrm{Inv}$: indeed if $f\in \mathcal{S}$ then so is $ g:=\mathrm{Inv} f$
  $$\frac{d}{dx}\ g = \mathrm{Inv} \circ \frac{d}{dx}\circ\mathrm{Inv}\ g \quad\Longrightarrow\quad   \mathrm{Inv} \circ \frac{d}{dx}\ g = \mathrm{Inv} \circ \mathrm{Inv} \circ \frac{d}{dx}\circ\mathrm{Inv}\ g = \frac{d}{dx}\circ\mathrm{Inv}\ g $$
  The equation can in fact be understood as commutation of the derivation operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ and that of taking the inverse
  $$\frac{d}{dx}\circ \mathrm{Inv}\ f = \mathrm{Inv} \circ \frac{d}{dx}\ f  \label{Eq}\tag{Eq}$$
  The contradiction I had hoped to get if $(\mathcal{S},\circ)$ were a group, was to exhibit a stable subvector space, and show that a group for $\circ$ could not contain a vector space, but $\mathcal{S}$ is not stable under composition!!! To do so, I assumed $\mathcal{A}:=\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}) \hookrightarrow H^1(\mathbb{R})$ (Sobolev space, or any space on which one could "diagonalize" $\frac{d}{dx}$, by Fourier transform usually). As a consequence of (\ref{Eq}), $\mathrm{Inv}$ should preserve the eigenspaces of $\frac{d}{dx}$. If we really want to continue along this line, I think we have to define a new kind of algebraic structure...
- "Reciprocal" function also appear when one does a change of variable in integration, so one could also get an integral version of the equation $g'=h$ in the case $\mathcal{A}:= \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$
  $$\begin{split}
  g(y)-g(0) &=\int_0^y g'(w)\, dw = \int_0^y h(w)\, dw =\genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{0}{z:=h(w)}{dz = h'(w)\, dw = \frac{1}{f''\circ h(w)}\, dw}\\
  &= \int_0^{h(y)} f''(z)\, z\, dz = \left[z\, f'(z) \right]^{h(y)}_0 - \int_0^{h(y)} f'(z)\, dz\\
  &= h(y)\times y -\big(f\circ h(y) - f(0) \big)
  \end{split}$$
- Could there be power series solution? From the comments, the attempt with $f(x):= a x^{b} $ involved functions of the form $\sqrt[b]{x}$ and $\sqrt[b-1]{x}$ so maybe instead of looking at power series, one may look at sums of functions of this form $\sqrt[n]{x}$.
- Can't we adapt some fixed point techniques? (very explicitly, start with some function $f_0,\ \Delta(f_0):=\frac{d}{dx}f_0^{\langle-1\rangle} - \left(\frac{d}{dx}f_0\right)^{\langle-1\rangle}$ not necessarily $0$ and look for some transformation $T$ s.t. $\Delta \big(T(f_0)\big)$ is closer to $0$ and so on). In particular for the case $\mathcal{A}:=\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ where inversion is symmetry w.r.t the diagonal in the plane $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ where we represent the graph of the function.

---

---

**Trick to give an algebraic formulation of the argument based on monotonicity:** define the action of translation on functions. If we want to break it into small steps, we can define translation by a constant $h\in \mathbb{R}$ acting on $\mathcal{A}:= \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$
$$\tau_h: \left\lbrace \begin{aligned} \mathcal{A}\quad & \longrightarrow \quad \mathcal{A}\\ "f(t)" & \longmapsto "f(t-h) "\end{aligned} \right. \in GL(\mathcal{A}) $$
More generally the action of the translation group is defined by the group morphism
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned} \big(\mathbb{R},+\big)  & \longrightarrow  \big(GL(\mathcal{A}),\circ \big)\\ h\quad & \longmapsto\quad \tau_h \end{aligned} \right. \label{A}\tag{A}$$
To imitate the other reasoning, based on the formula for the derivative of a composition (\ref{1}-\ref{2}), we need to show that left hand side and r.h.s. of (\ref{Eq}) do not behave in the same way under (\ref{A}).

Answer (score 1):

I foud [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeq6an44Rb8&list=WL&index=42) about complex solutions to the problem of the form $Cx^N$:

$$\frac{d}{dx} f^{\langle -1 \rangle}(x) = \left(\frac{d}{dx} f(x) \right)^{\langle -1 \rangle} \quad \to \;
\frac{ x^\frac{1-N}{N}}{NC^\frac{1}{N}} = \left(\frac{x}{CN} \right)^\frac{1}{N-1}$$

This only holds when $\quad \frac{1-N}{N} = \frac{1}{N-1} \qquad N^2-N+1=0 \qquad 
N = \frac{1 \, \pm \, i \sqrt{3}}{2} = e^{\pm \frac{i \pi}{3}}$

and $\quad NC^\frac{1}{N} = (CN)^\frac{1}{N-1} \qquad C = N^{(N-2)N}= 
\pm \, ie^{\pm \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}} \;$ or $\; e^{\pm \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}}$

Comment: Excellent post (+1)! But alas, I can't reproduce the last simplification $C=N^{(N-2)N}=$ ??

Comment: To be completely sure, I have formulated the discrepancy between your thoughts and mine as a question:
[Simplify $N^{N(N-2)}$ with $N=(1\pm i\sqrt{3})/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114663/simplify-nnn-2-with-n-1-pm-i-sqrt3-2).
And so it seems that the very last part of your answer is not entirely correct.

Comment: The two solutions simplified correctly:
$$
y = -i.e^{\pi/\sqrt{3}/2}.x^{1/2+i.\sqrt{3}/2} \\
y = +i.e^{\pi/\sqrt{3}/2}.x^{1/2-i.\sqrt{3}/2}
$$