# Simplify $N^{N(N-2)}$ with $N=(1\pm i\sqrt{3})/2$

Tags: complex-numbers

The question [Derivative and inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029021/derivative-and-inverse/)
is accompanied with an interesting [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029021/derivative-and-inverse/4068384#4068384)
by the same [author](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/850442/christian) and a nice video called
[Inverse Prime equals Prime Inverse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeq6an44Rb8&list=WL&index=43).
The video ends with the formula $C = N^{N(N-2)}$, which is simplified further in the author's answer to the question.
The problem is that I have not been able to reproduce this simplification. This is what I have done.

First solution:
$$
N = (1+i\sqrt{3})/2=e^{i\pi/3} \\
N(N-2)=(N^2-N+1)-(N+1)=-(N+1) \\
C = N^{-(N+1)} = \left(e^{i\pi/3}\right)^{(-3/2-i\sqrt{3}/2)} = e^{-i\pi/2}e^{\pi/(2\sqrt{3})}=-i\,e^{\pi/(2\sqrt{3})}
$$
Second solution:
$$
N = (1-i\sqrt{3})/2=e^{-i\pi/3} \\
C = N^{-(N+1)} = \left(e^{-i\pi/3}\right)^{(-3/2+i\sqrt{3}/2)} = e^{i\pi/2}e^{\pi/(2\sqrt{3})}=+i\,e^{\pi/(2\sqrt{3})}
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can easily check that with Mathematica or WolframAlpha

Comment: The number $N=\sqrt[3]{-1}$ where the answers are the complex roots.

Comment: @polfosol: Thanks for the response. Usually I check my mathematics with MAPLE. But there is only an old version (8) of it available on my PC, which doesn't perform very well on complex numbers.

Comment: WolframAlpha is technically free for such calculations. And in case you want to dive a little deeper into the world of Mathematica, there is the [online version](https://www.open.wolframcloud.com), also free ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a function who's derivative of the inverse equals the inverse of its derivative?
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f^{\langle-1\rangle}(x)=\left(\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)^{\langle-1\rangle}
$$
With functions of the form $y=Cx^N$ the answer is affirmative for complex $N$ and $C$.

The two solutions (when simplified correctly) are:
$$
y = -i.e^{\pi/\sqrt{3}/2}.x^{1/2+i.\sqrt{3}/2} \\
y = +i.e^{\pi/\sqrt{3}/2}.x^{1/2-i.\sqrt{3}/2}
$$